# Function with garbage at the end of the string (tried with NULL)

Tags: c, null

Im a beginner and i've looked everywhere for this solution but without result. What im trying to do, is a function that return the greater value for two numbers.
However, the output brings me some garbage number, and thats my problem.
Heres my code

```
   #include <stdio.h>
   #include <stdlib.h>
   #include <conio.h>

int largest(int num1, int num2)
{
    int biggest;
    if (num2 > num1) {
        printf("%d is bigger than %d\n\0", num2, num1);
    }
    if (num1 > num2){
        printf("%d is bigger than %d\n", num1, num2);
    }
    if (num1 == num2) {
        printf("%d and %d are equal\n", num1, num2);
    }
}


int main()

{

    printf("%d\n", largest(2, 4));

    return(0);
    getchar();

}
```

I've tried to use \0 at the end of my string but my output still gives me this:

```
4 is bigger than 2
2
```

The duece at the end is my problem(sometimes its a different character), how do i get rid of it? And again, the point here is the function, i can do it without a function but i want to learn functions.
Thanks!

Comment: change `printf("%d\n", largest(2, 4));` to `largest(2, 4);` you already do the printf in the function.

Comment: You don't seem to have a clear idea of which function's responsibility it is to do the printing. `largest` prints a message, but then `main` calls `printf` expecting `largest` to return an `int`.

Comment: Also, the `getchar` after the `return` has no effect.

Comment: Apart from duplication, the major problem is your `int` function does not return any value, so you print an undefined value in `main()`. The compiler would tell you this, if you looked at the warnings.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your function is not returning any value, so the `printf` in `main` prints garbage. The function is also duplicating the print in `main`. Here is a simple remedy.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int largest(int num1, int num2)
{
    return num1 > num2 ? num1 : num2;
}

int main(void)
{
    printf("%d\n", largest(2, 4));
    return 0;
}
```

Program output:

```
4
```

Comment: As long as you are implementing, what about if `num1` == `num2`?  It appears the answer would incorrectly indicate `num2`.

Comment: @ryyker that is not what was asked. OP asked why there is garbage, that his function is supposed to return a value. I simplified the code to illustrate why.

Comment: @ryyker please explain why `4` would be the wong answer for `largest(4, 4)`. Are you saying it should have been the *other* `4`? It returns the larger value of two numbers, so my own quibble is that the function should be called `larger`.

Comment: I handled this situation in the answer below

Comment: @WeatherVane - Lol, point taken.  I truly failed to see that when I commented.  Wow, too much going on.  Nice answer.

Answer (score 1):

1. `getchar()` is after `return` in the main function.
2. the first line of output is from function `largest()`.
3. the second line of output `2` is the function return value printed by `printf()`, since you don't have any return value inside the function, it will output the default return value.

Solution: Don't call function inside `printf()`. you can call function directly.

> `largest(2,4);` instead of `printf("%d\n", largest(2, 4));`
>             or add return statement inside function where ever necessary.

Comment: this has no effect on his question

Comment: @Hogan - OP really asks only one question.  This answer addresses it. ( _how do i get rid of it?_ ).  As for the rest, it is valid and useful information.

Answer (score 1):

The computer is printing an extra number **because you told it to**:

```
printf("%d\n", largest(2, 4));
```

If you *don't* want to print the return value of `largest(2, 4)`, then change this to just:

```
largest(2, 4);
```

Answer (score 0):

You do not return any value from your largest() function. e.g `return num1;` when num1 is larger.

```
int largest(int num1, int num2)
{
    int biggest;
    if (num2 > num1) 
        return num2;
    else
       return num1;
}
```

But this implementation has a problem as well: what if the number are equal.  You would have no way of determining that with this interface as it appears to be defined such that the return value is the larger of the two.

An alternate way to implement this would be to have the function return -1 if num1 > num2, 1 of num2 > num1 and 0 if the values were equal.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv);
int largest(int num1, int num2, int* largestValue);

/*******************************************/
/* function that compares two numbers and  */
/* returns:                                */
/*    -1 if num1 > num2                    */
/*     1 if num2 > num1                    */
/*     0 if num1 == num2                   */
/* if the return value is not 0 then the   */
/* larger of the numbers is copied into    */
/* the location pointed to by largestValue */
/*******************************************/
int largest(int num1, int num2, int *largestValue)  {
   int rc = 0;

   if (num1 > num2) {
      rc = -1;
      *largestValue = num1;
   } else if (num2 > num1) {
      rc = 1;
      *largestValue = num2;
   }

   return rc;
}


/* run pgm with "pgname num1 num2" */
int main(int argc, char **argv)  {
   int largestNum;
   int num1=atoi(argv[1]);
   int num2=atoi(argv[2]);

   int rc = largest(num1, num2, &largestNum);

   if (rc != 0)
      printf("Largest of %d and %d is %d\n", num1, num2, largestNum);
   else
      printf("The numbers are equal");

   return 0;
}
```

But that really seems like overkill to have a function whose purpose was to return the larger of two values.  Most if not all standard libraries provide max() macro that do what you were originally trying with your largest() function.

Comment: this has no effect on his question

Comment: he would still get the wrong output even with this change.

Comment: The question as I read it is "the output gives me some garbage number".  I assume the garbage number is the value 2 printed by the first line in main() as it is trying to print the larger of the values 2 and 4 which clearly is not 2.  My answer fixes that problem.  I assumed the printfs were debugging aids and he's not complaining about too much output rather that the function he wrote is not working.  Which it wasn't because it returned nothing explicitly.

Comment: see this is where we don't agree -- I don't think it is trying to print anything -- I think the programmer does not know what the printf statement does.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is here:

```
printf("%d\n", largest(2, 4));
```

You're printing the return value of the `largest` function, but you aren't returning any value from that function.

Update your function to return the larger value in each of the cases:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <conio.h>

int largest(int num1, int num2)
{
    if (num2 > num1) {
        printf("%d is bigger than %d\n", num2, num1);
        return num2;
    } else if (num1 > num2){
        printf("%d is bigger than %d\n", num1, num2);
        return num1;
    } else {
        printf("%d and %d are equal\n", num1, num2);
        return num1;
    }
}


int main()

{

    printf("%d\n", largest(2, 4));

    return(0);
}
```

Comment: this would still have the same problem it would just print 4 not 2

Comment: Could be simplified by removing all the unnecessary `else` clauses you introduced following `return`. It *looks* as though not all paths return a value.

Comment: @WeatherVane The way it was set up before with only `if`s, it's possible that there could be a path that doesn't return if the conditions have a bug in them.  With the `if`...`else` structure here, than ensures that all paths return.

Comment: @AndrewFalanga - we are not told the point -- we are told the "2" is garbage.  Solution: take out the line that prints it.

Comment: @dbush my point was you don't need an `else` after a `return` or a `break` or a `goto`.

Comment: @Hogan  We are told the point:  "What im trying to do, is **a function that return the greater value for two numbers**. However, the **output brings me some garbage number, and thats my problem**", i.e. the fact that the value is garbage is the issue, not the fact that there's something there at all.